# Frequency-independent way to determine AC mains RMS voltage

Tags: ac, opto-isolator, isolation

I'm looking for a circuit to determine the RMS voltage of the AC mains supply regardless of its frequency.

The monitoring circuit needs to be isolated from the AC mains, and I can't use a transformer. I've seen some circuits using optocouplers, but they seem to be frequency-dependent.

*Update*

Below is an example that ive found that would seemingly work well for my application, but changing the mains frequency changes the frequency of the pulses.
[How to measure AC voltage using non-linear opto-couplers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/588898/how-to-measure-ac-voltage-using-non-linear-opto-couplers)

Comment: so AC mains frequency puts this in the range of 45 to maybe 75 Hertz. I don't think that's going to be hard for any optoisolated measurement IC. Can you refer us to one of your optocoupler-based circuits that are so frequency-dependent that they don't work at these low frequencies?

Comment: _”seem to be frequency dependent”_ Please show!

Comment: also, can you explain *why* you can't use a transformer? I think this sounds a bit like you're thinking of big bulky transformers, while I think of things like measurement clamps, which are also transformers. So, I'm not sure I understand the restriction well enough to base recommendations of it.

Comment: send it through an FBR, then filter the DC with a 400v cap, then run it through a voltage divider "load". You can now read the divided voltage and scale it to ~RMS line voltage. If you need more precision than a volt or two, you'll have to get more complicated.

Comment: Use an incandescent lamp and photovoltaic cell -- good isolation and frequency independence to RF, though with limited range and requiring calibration, since light output is highly nonlinear. Make a paper scale for a d'Arsonval mA (or µA) meter for the photocell output.

Comment: This is one example i have seen that seems to be frequency dependent. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/588898/how-to-measure-ac-voltage-using-non-linear-opto-couplers

Comment: Could you refer me to the part number of a mains rater optoisolated measurement IC?

Comment: If you truly need RMS, and not just an assumed value, note that RMS can be done with random (specifically, uncorrelated and evenly distributed) sampling of any waveform.  I'm not sure this helps much with respect to isolation, but it is frequency independent.

Comment: An isolation amplifier like HCPL-7800 could be an option.

Comment: What is your application?